# Uncaught GuzzleHttp\Exception\ConnectException: cURL error 7

Tags: php, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

So I'm using the `azure-storage-php` library (https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-php) and everything works perfectly and all of my scripts work, but I'm getting the following error from time to time:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught GuzzleHttp\Exception\ConnectException: cURL error 7: Failed to connect to fz.blob.core.windows.net port 443: Connection refused (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)
```

Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong? Below is the code that I have that is mainly based on the library:

```
public function connect()
{
    $connection_string = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;
    AccountName={$this->account_name};
    AccountKey={$this->account_key}";
    $blob_client = BlobRestProxy::createBlobService($connection_string);

    return $blob_client;
}

public function generate_sas_url(string $blob, string $duration): string
    {
        $sas_helper = new BlobSharedAccessSignatureHelper(
            $this->account_name,
            $this->account_key,
        );

        $token = $sas_helper->generateBlobServiceSharedAccessSignatureToken(
            Resources::RESOURCE_TYPE_BLOB,
            "$this->container_name/{$blob}",
            'r',
            (new \DateTime())->modify($duration),
            (new \DateTime()),
            '',
            'https',
        );

        $connection_string_sas = Resources::BLOB_ENDPOINT_NAME .
            '=' .
            'https://' .
            $this->account_name .
            '.' .
            Resources::BLOB_BASE_DNS_NAME . ';' .
            Resources::SAS_TOKEN_NAME . '=' .
            $token;

        $blob_client_sas = BlobRestProxy::createBlobService($connection_string_sas);

        $blob_url_sas = sprintf(
            '%s%s?%s',
            (string)$blob_client_sas->getPsrPrimaryUri(),
            "$this->container_name/{$blob}",
            $token,
        );

        return $blob_url_sas;
    }
```

Comment: Does it sometimes work on that URL and sometimes fail? Or does it work on some URLs but fail on others?

Comment: Also had that problem, sadly i can't find that code anymore. Check if it works without https. If remeber correctly there is a setting somewhere in azure for https.

Comment: shelly1337 Greg thanks guys! I ended up finding the issue, looks like I needed a try/catch on my connection everywhere I was calling it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seemed to have fixed the issue:

```
public function blob_exists(string $name, string $prefix = ''): int
{
    try {
        $list_blobs_options = new ListBlobsOptions();
        $list_blobs_options->setPrefix($prefix . $name . '.jpg');
        $results = $this->connect()->listBlobs(
            $this->container_name, $list_blobs_options
        );
        return count($results->getBlobs());
    } catch (ConnectException $e) {
        $code = $e->getCode();
        $error_message = $e->getMessage();
        echo $code . ": " . $error_message . PHP_EOL;
        return 0;
    }
}
```

I've have a method that checks if blobs exist, make sure to try/catch your connector method and also include `catch (ConnectException)`.